# Production Rails 3 Routes not working the same as Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am currently trying to get my Ruby (1.8.7) on Rails (3.0.9) application running in a production environment.  However on transferring across to the production environment I am having major problems with my routes.  For instance in my code I referred to

```
user_path()
```

But in production I had to change that to

```
users_path()
```

That seems to be working except where it is used in

```
users_path(user)
```

Which produces the URL

```
http://whatwillworkforme.com/users?format=myuser
```

Whereas development would produce:

```
http://whatwillworkforme.com/users/myuser
```

My routes are shown below.  I am using code the Smartr project (https://github.com/dkd/smartr) so I am not that familiar with Rails 3 routes or why particular decisions were made.

```
WhatWillWorkForMeCom::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations",
                                   :passwords      => "passwords",
                                   :sessions      => "sessions" }
  namespace :admin do
    resources :comments
    resources :treatments
    resources :conditions
    resources :users
  end

  match "/conditions/page/:page", :to => "conditions#index"
  match "/conditions/hot(/:page)", :to => "conditions#hot"
  match "/conditions/active(/:page)", :to => "conditions#active"
  match "/conditions/untreated(/:page)", :to => "conditions#untreated"
  match "/conditions/tagged/:tag(/:page)", :to => "condition#index"

  match "sitemap/" => "sitemap#index"

  match 'contact_us' => 'site#contact_us_new', :as => 'contact_us', :via => :get
  match 'contact_us' => 'site#contact_us_create', :as => 'contact_us', :via => :post

  resources :conditions, :except => [:show, :edit] do

    member do
      put :update_for_toggle_acceptance
      put :update_for_toggle_decline
    end

    collection do
      get :hot
      get :active
      get :untreated
      get :search
    end
  end

  match "/conditions/:id(/:friendly_id)", :to => "conditions#show", :as => :condition
  match "/conditions/:id/:friendly_id/edit", :to => "conditions#edit"
  match "/site/terms_and_conditions", :to => "site#terms_and_conditions"

  scope "/conditions/:condition_id/:friendly_id/" do
    get "treatment/:id/edit", :to => "treatments#edit", :as => :edit_condition_treatment
    put "treatment/:id", :to => "treatments#update", :as => :condition_treatment
    post "treatments", :to => "treatments#create", :as => :condition_treatments
  end

  match "/admin", :to => "admin#index"

  resources :comments
  resources :tags, :only => [:index]
  resources :votes, :only => [:create]

  resources :users, :except => [:destroy] do

    collection do
      get :who_is_online
      get :search
    end

    member do
      get :reputation
    end

    resources :bookmarks, :only => [:index]

  end

  resources :bookmarks, :only => [:toggle] do
    member do
      post :toggle
      get :toggle
    end
  end

  match "errors/routing", :to => "errors#routing"

  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :conditions, :only => [:index]
      resources :users, :only => [:index]
    end
  end

  root :to => 'site#index'
  match '*a', :to => 'errors#routing'
end
```

Rake Routes (as asked for) is

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)         {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
    destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)        {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)        {:action=>"create", :controller=>"passwords"}
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)    {:action=>"new", :controller=>"passwords"}
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"passwords"}
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"passwords"}
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)          {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"registrations"}
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                 {:action=>"create", :controller=>"registrations"}
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"registrations"}
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)            {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"registrations"}
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                 {:action=>"update", :controller=>"registrations"}
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                 {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"registrations"}
       user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)    {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
   new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format){:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
                         GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)    {:action=>"show", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
who_is_online_users GET    /users/who_is_online(.:format)      {:action=>"who_is_online", :controller=>"users"}
       search_users GET    /users/search(.:format)             {:action=>"search", :controller=>"users"}
    reputation_user GET    /users/:id/reputation(.:format)     {:action=>"reputation", :controller=>"users"}
     user_bookmarks GET    /users/:user_id/bookmarks(.:format) {:action=>"index", :controller=>"bookmarks"}
              users GET    /users(.:format)                    {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
                    POST   /users(.:format)                    {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
           new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
          edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)           {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
               user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
                    PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
```

Comment: `user_path` should work. Doesn't it?

Comment: In development yes but not in production.  Its got me mystified :)

Comment: Do you get error in production?

Comment: If I put user_path back in the error is "ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}):" and there is a show method on UsersController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why development and production behaviors differ, but `http://whatwillworkforme.com/users?format=myuser` is actually the expected behavior on `users_path(myuser)`. You can validate this by running `rake routes`. You should get something along these lines:

```
users GET    /users(.:format)        users#index
 user GET    /users/:id(.:format)    users#show
```

Anything with a starting colon in the routes will be an argument you can pass to `url_for` or anything that uses it, eg. `link_to`.

You should be using `user_path(user)` to get the route of a specific user (Rails will translate an ActiveRecord instance to its `id` before passing it into the route).

Conversely, you should be using `users_path` with no argument as you're referring to the entire collection using a plural route. Any argument will try to give a format to your url (eg. `'xml'` should add a trailing `.xml` to the url).

In your specific case, also watch out for a duplicated route: `POST` calls to `/users` will be intercepted by Devise and won't reach your controller `create` action.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I have set the appropriate user_path, users_path.  I'm trying the rake routes but having some problem with getting rake to run as it seems to be trying to do everything in development mode rather than production.  Will have to contact hosting company.

Comment: Try this: `RAILS_ENV=production rake routes`, or better yet, do `export RAILS_ENV=production` on your production machine so that all requests are made in the production environment.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm with RailsPlayground and it turns out that everything is development unless explicitly stated.  The routes you specified aren't present in the rake routes (I have included above).  Sorry for the delay in responding but work and kids kill a lot of time :)

Comment: Sorry thought the list was in alphabetical order.  Yes it does include the routes you specified.  Will try to work out what I need to add to the routes to get my code working correctly

Comment: That basically did it.  I also had to change the user_path(user) to user_path(user.login).  Both ways worked in development but only the latter worked in production.  Always thought RoR was a bit more predictable than that.

Comment: You use `login` to identify your user; `user_path(user)` was not working because if it finds an object as a parameter, it automatically sends `id` to get its id :) Anyhow, glad I could help!